# Operator convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

How to solve the following:

Operator $A_n: C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ is given with $A_n(f)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n})\binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$. Does $A_n$ converges uniformly, strong and weak, when $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should call $A_n(f)$ $B_n(f)$, since it is the so-called [Bernstein polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) of $f$. The key property of the latter (which implies Stone-Weiertstrass) is that $B_n(f)\rightarrow f$ uniformly, i.e. for the sup norm over $[0,1]$. That is $B_n\rightarrow Id$ strongly whence weakly.

Comment: I tried to use Banach-Steinhaus theorem of convergence. Using the binomial formula, I got that $|A_n(f)|\leq \|f\|$ and $\|A_n\|\leq 1$. Also, $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,...\}$ is fundamental set in $C[0,1]$, but I am having trouble to evaluate limit on fundamental set. How should I do this?

Comment: As @julien mentioned, $A_n$ converges strongly to the identity. However, $A_n$ does not converge uniformly. To see this, for every $n$, let $f\in C[0,1]$ be such that $\|f\|=1$ but $f(\frac{k}{n})=0$ for $0\le k\le n$. Then $A_nf=0$, and hence $\|A_n-\mathrm{id}\|\ge 1$.

Comment: How to prove that $B_n\rightarrow Id$ strongly?

Comment: I just saw your last comment. Who were you asking? If you reply someone's comment under your post, you should @someone to remind him/her. Please note that there is a proof of strong convergence in the linked page given by julien. This proof or some other proof can also be found in many standard analysis textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Lemma 48 on page 45 [on this note](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hanche/notes/fnal/fnal.pdf). (Disclaimer: I wrote that note.)